# Negative Mean with Positive Standard Deviation

Tags: statistics

The mean for a sample I collected = $-60.75$. Its associated standard deviation is $179.44$. My question is, if the range of values for this particular sample is restricted such that NO X-VALUE exceeds $0$, how can the standard deviation be this large? From my understanding, a M = $-60.75$ and a SD = $179.4$ indicate that approximately $68\%$ of this sample ranges from $-240.15$ to $+118.65$. However, given the restriction noted above, how can this be accurate? Is my understanding of how these two descriptives function incorrect? Thank you.

Comment: I assume you are saying that all numbers are negative. There could still be a big standard deviation if the distribution has a "fat" left tail. The $68\%$ stuff that you quote is for roughly normally distributed random variables.  Note for example that an exponentially distributed random variable has mean and standard deviation $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ but is nowhere negative. So the negative of an exponentially distributed random variable will behave somewhat like yours.

Answer (score 1):

If the PDF of the variable is
$$
f(x)=\frac4\pi\frac{x}{1+x^4}\,[x\ge0]
$$
where $[\cdots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

The mean is therefore
$$
\frac4\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt2
$$
Yet the variance, hence the standard deviation, is infinite since
$$
\frac4\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{x(x-\sqrt2)^2}{1+x^4}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
diverges.

As with the distribution above, this implies that the distribution is non-symmetric, a lot of the variance is contributed by the tail to the right of the mean.

Answer (score 0):

The sigma rule only holds if the variable is normally distributed! 
In your case, it is probably because it all lies in the negative values? Just imagine a high variance distribution and then shifted to the left (take away a large value). Or it can have fat tail. I suggest plot the data in some software as a histogram, or density approximation and it will be clear.